# How to SkippCall while Hooking in Deviare?

Tags: python, api, hook

Does anyone how to SkipCall() in Deviare (Python)?
They say something like:
HRESULT     SkipCall ()
    Skip calling the original function. 
When I try to do this, it doesn't work. It goes in a loop at the same call. I guess that I should also do some stuff on registers (like to restore EBP). But the thing is that NktCallInfo.Register set doesn't work in Python. I try something like:

```
NktHookCallInfo.Register(ESP, EBP)
```

But it doesn't work. Help please ?

Answer (score 3):

I recently see this question. Expect not to be late. (I'm a Deviare developer)

When you call SkipCall, you must setup a return value and, optionally the Win32 lasterror using the provided 'INktHookCallInfo' methods. If the function being hooked is in the database, it will remove the parameters from stack depending on the calling convention.

If you are hooking an arbitrary address without assigning a function, you must do the unwind manually by setting the ESP/RSP registers as appropiate.